# How to pull out backend code from an Azure function into a sub repository while keeping git history?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github, azure-functions

I have an Azure function project within a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TMason11095/anki-japanese-flashcard-manager) (AnkiSentenceCardBuilder being the Azure function project) and I want to pull the backend code out into a new sub repository, so I can reuse it with other presentation layers, such as a WinForm.

In order to keep the Git history, I planned on updating the current repository to add a Class Library project, move all the backend code into that new project, clone the repository, and delete the Azure function project.

My issue with that is after creating the Class Library project, I get the error `Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]`. I'm assuming this is because the Azure function is trying to treat the Class Library as an Azure function. Since it's not suppose to be an Azure function, I can't fix this by calling `func init` on the new project, as that converts my Class Library into an Azure function.

How would I go about doing this?
For extra context, I'm pretty new to both Git and Azure and am working on this within VS with C#.

Comment: On the new project, if you remove the newly added class you can then successfuly call func init?

Comment: @ojonasplima I can remove the Class Library project and the program will work again, if that's what you mean. Unless you mean call `func init` on the main Azure function project in order for it to not show that error when I re-add the Class Library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Visual Studio, include a new Class Library project within your solution. I have named it YourbackendLibrary.

My repository structure:-

[image]

***Command to create new class library:-***

```bash
dotnet new classlib -n YourLibraryName
```

**Output:-**

[image]

- Transfer the backend code with all the classes and utilities from the AnkiSentenceCardBuilder project to the recently added Class Library project.
- Verify that the Class Library project is correctly configured as a Class Library, ensuring it targets the appropriate framework and output type.
- Eliminate any references or dependencies associated with Azure Functions from the Class Library project.
- If your Function code is part of Services folder, make sure you move all the classes and utilities with Function code to the newly created class library and then refactor your code with all the required dependencies.
- After moving and verifying the code, commit changes to the Git repository to maintain history. Clone the repository elsewhere to replicate the updated structure without the Azure Function project. Clean up by deleting the Azure Function project from the original repository and commit this change. Ensure to update references if reusing the Class Library, such as adding it to your WinForms project.